# Trying to verify a download signature with PGP, but getting "no signed data" when passing in the .asc file?

Tags: signature, pgp

I tried the following steps from [Verifying Signatures](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) on the Tor Project:

gpg.exe --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290

```
  imported: 1
```

gpg.exe --fingerprint 0x4E2C6E8793298290

```
  pub   4096R/93298290 2014-12-15 [expires: 2020-08-24]
  Key fingerprint = EF6E 286D DA85 EA2A 4BA7  DE68 4E2C 6E87 9329 8290
  uid       [ unknown] Tor Browser Developers (signing key) <torbrowser@torproject.org>
  sub   4096R/D9FF06E2 2018-05-26 [expires: 2020-09-12]
```

gpg.exe --verify C:\Users\Cyn\Desktop\torbrowser-install-win64-8.0.4_en-US.exe.asc

```
  gpg: no signed data
  gpg: can't hash datafile: No data
```

The file looks like this:

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

blah blah blah/E
=oakm

-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

So what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 6):

**It's a detached signature** and you need the data.

The Tor package signatures, like many other package signatures using PGP/GPG you will find on the net, are what PGP/GPG calls a detached signature -- the data is in one (often large) file, and the signature is in a second, separate (small) file. That's why there are two download links (or buttons) -- one for the actual software package and one for the separate/detached signature. In order to verify a detached signature on data you also need the data (and the public key); e.g. for Windows you need

```
torbrowser-install-win64-8.0.4_en-US.exe -- the (relevant) data file 
torbrowser-install-win64-8.0.4_en-US.exe.asc -- the signature
```

Notice how the filenames have the same base, but the signature has `.asc` added at the end. If you run `gpg[.exe] --verify file.asc` where `file.asc` is a detached signature, gpg automatically looks for the data in `file` -- and fails if it's not there. (Similarly for `file.sig` and `file` for a binary aka 'unarmored' signature.)

The page you link actually says "Assuming you downloaded the package and its signature to your Desktop ..." Notice *package* AND *its signature*.

If you actually have the data file but under a different name (including a different directory), *or* if it's under the defaulted name but you want to be explicit (which the GPG manual now recommends), specify *both* filenames:

```
 gpg[.exe] --verify sigfile.asc datafile
```